# Help with syntax in order to replace url by another

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, I am trying to automatically replace every...

www.mywebsite.com/blog/category/categoryname

by

www.mywebsite.com/blog/#categoryname

...in my page.

```
$("a[href^='...']")
 .each(function()
 { 
  this.href = this.href.replace(...);
 }
);
```

Can someone help with the syntax please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `/category/` is actual, but `categoryname` varies. If that's correct, do this:

```
this.href = this.href.replace( '/category/', '/#' );
```

or a similar approach:

```
this.href = this.href.split('/category/').join('/#');
```

Comment: Thank you I ended up using the

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[href*=category]').attr('href', function(i,h){ return h.replace(/category\//,'#'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following

```
$(".cat-menu a[href*=category]")
        .each(function()
        { 
        this.href = this.href.replace( "/category/", "/#" );
        }
    );
```

Thank you